# How can I hide and show a section using a conditional statement and PDF generator?

Tags: pdf, twig, pdf-generation, octobercms, craftcms

Using craft CMS I am adding an option to be able to hide a section from a PDF.
The PDF is created using PHP and a library called Snappy.
The light-switch is turned off (0) by default.
I have added the conditional statement and the light-switch, tested by wrapping other sections of the site (not part of the PDF) inside the if condition.
When turning the light-switch on and off I am able to hide and show sections.
The PDF does not seem to be working that way. The section is always hidden even when the light-switch is turned on.
I don't understand how the backend of the PDF works so is it something to do with how PDFs are generated?
Also it's showing blank pages where the content "would" be which is not desired.

//====Master PDF layout

```
{% extends 'abc/pdf/_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% include 'abc/pdf/_section1.html' %}
    {% include 'abc/pdf/_section2.html' %}
    {% include 'abc/pdf/_section3.html' %}
    {% include 'abc/pdf/_section4.html' %}
    {% include 'abc/pdf/_section5.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

//==== Section with condition (abc/pdf/_section4.html)

```
{% if (entry.showsection4 is defined and entry.showsection4) and dateRanges | length %}
    <div class="page">
        <div class="page__inner">
          A bunch of content in section 4 that I want to hide and show
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: how you generate PDF where you defined switch can you share those infos.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya it's a field in the cms with the handle "showsection4" -  . The field is a lightswitch